# How to restrict resource usage and access of users doing labs (like in Qwiklabs)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm wondering how Qwiklabs is restricting access and usage of resources.

If somone is doing a lab, the user could for example create a lot of VMs or use other resources that are not part of the steps in the lab.

I thought that quotas might stop a user from activity that he is not supposed to do. Or can the user just change the quotas? Can you stop them from changing quotas?

I also saw on Qwiklabs that they are giving you temporary credentials that you use to sign in and access Google Cloud for the duration of the lab. Can someone explain how this is a way to stop a user from activity he is not supposed to do?

I'm thankful for every answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering how Qwiklabs is restricting access and usage of
> resources.

Qwiklabs uses Stackdriver logging/auditing to monitor events on a user's ID. If an event occurs that is outside what the user should be doing, a security trigger is generated which usually results in the user's account being blocked. The user must then ask Qwiklabs to enable their account again. This could result in a permanent suspension of their account.

> If somone is doing a lab, the user could for example create a lot of
> VMs or use other resources that are not part of the steps in the lab.

If a user attempts to do things outside of the Qwiklab, their account is almost immediately blocked

> I thought that quotas might stop a user from activity that he is not supposed to do. Or can the user just change the quotas? Can you
> stop them from changing quotas?

Unless Qwiklabs has made a mistake in the lab creation (which has happened in the past), users do not have more privilege than necessary to do the labs. Users do not have the roles/permissions to modify their temporary accounts.

> I also saw on Qwiklabs that they are giving you temporary credentials
> that you use to sign in and access Google Cloud for the duration of
> the lab. Can someone explain how this is a way to stop a user from
> activity he is not supposed to do?

1. Credentials expire.
2. Stackdriver records events that are monitored by software.
3. Unexpected user activities result in an account block.
4. After a lab completes or an account block happens, all user resources are destroyed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One follow up question: What exactly do I have to do so that users don't have the roles/permissions to modify their temporary accounts? Is this done with IAM roles and service accounts? And for clarity: does this mean that quotas prevent users from lets say creating too many VMs and if we want to make sure that they also don't use other resources (they are not supposed to use) we use security triggers? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In regards to Qwilabs, there is nothing for you to do. You have no rights to the Qwilab systems other than paying for lab credits and using labs. Users only have rights that Qwiklabs grants them. You cannot affect or change anything. If a problem arises, report it to Google. I do recommend reading the Terms of Service: https://www.qwiklabs.com/terms_of_service